# CSS bottom property moves image to top of page

Tags: html, css

I have two images absolutely positioned within divs. If I remove the `bottom` property, the images are in place (I need to use `bottom` for fine positioning). If I add the `bottom` property, the images leave their `imageHeight` parent container and move to the top of the page.

Any idea why it's doing this?

HTML

```
    <div class="imageHeight">
        <div class="imageInline" id="rbMain"></div>
        <div class="imageInline" id="rbPhone"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
section#item1 #rbMain{
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 516px;
    background-image: url("../images/rb-large-pc.png");
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
}

section#item2 #rbPhone{
    right: 20%;
    width: 383px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url("../images/rb-large-phone.png");
    bottom: 5px;
}

.imageHeight{
    height: 516px;
}

section.showcase .imageInline{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To position 2 elements absolutely inside the parent, the parent itself should have position absolute or relative.

```
.imageHeight{
    position: relative;
    height: 516px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, I just added `background-position: bottom center;` and it's not forcing the image to the bottom of the parent div. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you swapped X with Y. You have to write center bottom. Bottom is not good as a X property. You should write background-position-x: center and background-position-y: bottom to do not get confused. Are you making a product browser for an online shop and you want to position some decoration over some products? in case check www.fabricjs.com

Answer (score 1):

try giving `position: relative` to `.imageHeight`

```
.imageHeight{
    height: 516px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, I just added `background-position: bottom center;` and it's not forcing the image to the bottom of the parent div. Any idea why?

Comment: `background-position` can take 
`left top` ||
`left center` ||
`left bottom` ||
`right top` ||
`right center` ||
`right bottom` ||
`center top` ||
`center center` ||
`center bottom` and by default its `center`

Comment: change `background-position: bottom center;` to `background-position: center bottom;`

Comment: try `display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom;` for images

Comment: Right, but these are background images. I don't think `vertical-align` works with background images, does it?